# How to update a table AND throw an error in the same trigger without raising ORA-04091 mutating table error

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, database-trigger

My homework requires me to create a single trigger which, under certain circumstances, updates a value AND raises an error. I am using an Oracle database which I access via the sqlplus command on a terminal.

- I cannot use « :NEW.attributeName := value » because raising the error prevents the update.
- I cannot use an update statement inside the trigger because it will raise a mutating table error.
- According to the problem statement I should be able to solve this within a single trigger and the problem statement is kind of vague on this but I think I am not allowed to use a procedure either.
- We have not seen temporary tables in class so they can't be used for the homework. We have however seen views.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER triggerName
INSTEAD OF UPDATE OF attributeName ON TableName
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (:NEW.attributeName < 0) THEN
        UPDATE  TableName
        SET attributeName = 0
        WHERE   attr0 = :NEW.attr0 AND
            attr1 = :NEW.attr1
        ;
        raise_application_error(-20101, 'You cannot update attributeName to a negative value.');
END;
/
```

I tried using a view as described in the following example (https://sgbd.developpez.com/oracle/ora-04091/#LI). It's in French; it just says that creating a view should allow you to use an INSTEAD OF trigger, but I did exactly that and now the trigger is no longer triggered when I update the table.

```
CREATE TABLE CLIENT(
    IDC INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ,
    NOM VARCHAR2 (40));

CREATE TABLE VOYAGE(
    IDV INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ,
    DESTINATION VARCHAR2 (40),
    MAXPLACE INTEGER ) -- nombre total de places     
;

CREATE TABLE INSCRIPTION(
    IDC INTEGER REFERENCES CLIENT(IDC),
    IDV INTEGER REFERENCES VOYAGE(IDV),
    DATERESERV DATE ,
    CONSTRAINT INSCRIPTION_PK PRIMARY KEY (IDC, IDV));

INSERT INTO CLIENT(IDC, NOM) VALUES (1, 'DURAND');
INSERT INTO CLIENT(IDC, NOM) VALUES (2, 'DUBOIS');
INSERT INTO CLIENT(IDC, NOM) VALUES (3, 'DUGENOU');
COMMIT ;

INSERT INTO VOYAGE(IDV, DESTINATION, MAXPLACE) VALUES (10, 'VENISE', 25);
INSERT INTO VOYAGE(IDV, DESTINATION, MAXPLACE) VALUES (11, 'PRAGUE', 20);
COMMIT ;

-- Création d'une vue sur la table INSCRIPTION pour le support des déclencheurs INSTEAD OF
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW V_INSCRIPTION AS SELECT * FROM INSCRIPTION;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRIG_V_INSCRIPTION INSTEAD OF INSERT ON V_INSCRIPTION FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE 
    NB_RESERVE INTEGER ; -- nombre de réservations déjà faites
    NB_MAXPLACE INTEGER ; -- nombre de places total

BEGIN 
    SELECT COUNT (*) INTO NB_RESERVE FROM V_INSCRIPTION 
    WHERE IDC=:NEW.IDC
    AND IDV=:NEW.IDV;
    SELECT MAXPLACE INTO NB_MAXPLACE FROM VOYAGE 
    WHERE IDV=:NEW.IDV;
    IF NB_MAXPLACE - NB_RESERVE < 1 THEN 
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Désolé, voyage complet');

    ELSE 
        -- dans un déclencheur INSTEAD OF, l'instruction DML sous-jacente ne s'exécute pas. On traite donc l'insertion manuellement
        INSERT INTO INSCRIPTION(IDC, IDV, DATERESERV) VALUES (:NEW.IDC, :NEW.IDV, :NEW.DATERESERV);
    END IF ;
END ;
/

-- DUGENOU aimerait bien aller à Venise :
INSERT INTO INSCRIPTION(IDC, IDV, DATERESERV) SELECT 3, 10, TO_DATE(SYSDATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY') FROM DUAL ;
1 ligne créée.
```

Is there any way for me to update the value of attributeName AND raise error ORA-20101 without using a procedure? Else, I'll assume I am allowed to.

Comment: Your description of the problem is ambiguous. The first Trigger you've shown is a `instead of  update` trigger and the second one is an `instead of insert`. Moreover, they seem to be doing completely different things. What exactly do you need to do? update or insert? When should the error be raised? after insert or after update?

Comment: The second was just an example I took inspiration from. I actually have to write a trigger for an update, not for an insert. Anyways, it turns out that the teacher meant us to use DBMS output when they said we needed to include an error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow. That's one heck of a set of requirements. First of all, if you want any of your changes to be preserved even though that exception is raised, you will want to create a separate procedure and use the pragma autonomous_transaction statement.

Second, the only way to avoid a mutating table trigger if you are updating the same table on which the trigger fires AND you can only have a single trigger is to use a *compound* trigger. Here's a link to a LiveSQL script that will give you lots of code to work from. https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_CGRC9SJRBTH83GTAAWUB1H4JG.html

Third, this is all a bad idea. A DML trigger should not contain DML itself. Too many potential problems and side-effects.

Instead, create a procedure that contains all the necessary logic and have developers call the procedure when performing an update.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to answer this.

It turns out that when the teacher told us to include an error message they meant to print a message, not to raise an exception with a message. Without raising an error, the problem becomes trivial as a BEFORE update trigger can put the desired value in :NEW.attributeName and not have it rollback because no error is raised.

Thanks for the link as well, it might come in handy for one of the other questions in the homework.

Comment: Great to see you here after a while!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the teacher meant us to use DBMS output to display an "error message" as opposed to actually raising an error. The solution then becomes

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER triggerName
BEFORE UPDATE OF attributeName ON TableName
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (:NEW.attributeName < 0) THEN
        :NEW.attributeName := 0;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('You cannot update attributeName to a negative value.');
END;
/
```